# Imported value should be converted to rows

Tags: mysql, excel, cell, rows

I have imported data to a excel cell from my mySQL database.

The format is like this: 1,24,34,414,44

My question is, how can I make that one cell split into new rows.

The result should be something like this:

```
(cell A1) 1
(cell A2)23
(cell A3)34
(cell A4)414
(cell A5)33
```

I hoped it would be possible to do it automatically, so when I import the data from my database, it will automatically split into rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the embedded split functionality of MS Excel

Menu
`Data -> Text to Columns`
and follow the wizard with comma `,` as delimiter character.

Edit:based on your comment
After this if you want to rotate data copy all data, try the following steps:

1. Copy the data in one or more columns or rows.
2. Before you paste the copied data, right-click your first destination cell (the first cell of the row or column into which you want to paste your data), and then click Paste Special.
3. In the Paste Special dialog box, select Transpose, and then click OK.

Comment: I add some steps to my answer to rotate your data ;)

Comment: That actually works. But it requires med to click. I need it to do it automatically. :) - Have hundreds of em'

Comment: You can replace comma character `,` with `new line` before import your data to excel

Comment: I can't find the "new line" in the External Data Properties, when I import from my database. Can you give me at hint ? It only displays all my information in one cell.